# How to filter array of BehaviorSubject?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have two rxjs objects:

```
   public documents: BehaviorSubject<ApplicationExistingRelationShips[]> = new BehaviorSubject<ApplicationExistingRelationShips[]>([]);
   public filteredDocuments: BehaviorSubject<ApplicationExistingRelationShips[]> = new BehaviorSubject<ApplicationExistingRelationShips[]>(
        [],
    );
```

And there is a function that filter documents and result pushed to `filteredDocuments`:

```
filterDocuments(term: string) {
        this.documents
            .pipe(
                tap((documents) => console.log(documents)),
                filter((documents) => documents.filter((doc) => doc.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1).length > 0),
            )
            .subscribe((filtered) => {
                console.log(filtered);
                this.filteredDocuments.next(filtered);
            });
    }
```

Problem is that I always get result `console.log(filtered);` as initial `documents` object with all values, not filtered. What do I do wrong?

Inside `tap()` I got an array of values, then I try to find elements of array where `name` is equal of `term`.

Comment: Why you are checking `.length > 0` after filter, it might become always true and returns entire documents instead of filtered documents

Comment: I need to check if inner filter returns true, is not ? How then?

Comment: I have mad this and it works: `this.documents
            .pipe(map((documents) => documents.filter((doc) => doc.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)))
            .subscribe((filtered) => {
                console.log(filtered);
                this.filteredDocuments.next(filtered);
            });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably confused the behaviour of Array.filter and rxjs' filter. You already found the solution to your issue, which is using `map` instead, but the underlying issue is that `filter` in rxjs is not used for filtering values of an array, but for filtering values from the stream.

Say you have a stream of numbers `-1-2-3-|`: This is, it emits 1, then 2, then 3, then completes. You can add a `filter(v => v >= 2)` to get `---2-3-|`.

If you look at your example, you don't have an observable of documents. You have an observable of arrays of documents - This means that `filter` would filter whether an array passes or not.... Maybe it would be useful if you want to get an observable which contains the list of documents with more elements than X.

This is why the one you were looking for is actually a `map` - On the original observable, you want to *change* every list of documents into another list of documents with its elements filtered.

Another note, one of the cool things of rxjs is that it's reactive: You can define streams that will react to other streams changing, without manually needing to read from one and updating another. So, unless you need to work with BehaviorSubjects specifically, your streams would be better represented as:

```
public documents: BehaviorSubject<ApplicationExistingRelationShips[]> = new BehaviorSubject<ApplicationExistingRelationShips[]>([]);
public filteredDocuments = documents.pipe(
   map(documents => documents.filter(doc => /*...*/))
)
```

This way, `filteredDocuments` is an observable that will filter the documents to your need, and you don't need to manually subscribe to `this.documents` and push new values to `filteredDocuments`